# Bash script to convert a string with space delimited tokens to an array

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, shell

I have a string

```
echo $STRING
```

which gives

```
first second third fourth fifth
```

basically a list separated spaces.

how do i take that string and make it an array so that

```
array[0] = first
array[1] = second
```

etc..

I have tried

```
IFS=' ' read -a list <<< $STRING
```

but then when i do an

```
echo ${list[@]}
```

it only prints out "first" and nothing else

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash

Comment: You've accepted an answer that is [explicitly documented as an antipattern](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's simple actually:

```
list=( $STRING )
```

Or more verbosely:

```
declare -a list=( $STRING )
```

PS: You can't export IFS and use the new value in the same command. You have to declare it first, then use its effects in the following command:

```
$ list=( first second third )
$ IFS=":" echo "${list[*]}"
first second third
$ IFS=":" ; echo "${list[*]}"
first:second:third
```

Notice that the last example will change `IFS` to `":"` until you change it again, or the shell exits.
Usually you want to use a subshell, or save the original value of `IFS` so you can restore it afterwards.

Comment: awesome that worked.  But how does it know what to split it by?

Comment: `IFS`' default value is ` \t\n\r` or something like that. When assigning to an array using the `()`-syntax everything between the parentheses gets expanded like parameters of a command, turning every "parameter" to an element of the array.

Comment: `list=( $STRING )` is an antipattern; see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29)

Answer (score 0):

Your original code generally works -- the quoting is a bit off (and how much that matters is version-specific: you wouldn't see your original bug on a newer version of bash), but nothing further.

After:

```
# assign string
string='this is several words'

# split string to a list
IFS=' ' read -r -a list <<<"$string"
```

...you can run:

```
# print a definition of the variable list
$ declare -p list
declare -a list=([0]="this" [1]="is" [2]="several" [3]="words")

# print each item in the list array on a separate line
$ printf ' - %s\n' "${list[@]}"
- this
- is
- several
- words

# still works with echo; change IFS to show that we're really an array
$ IFS=':' echo "${list[*]}"
this:is:several:words
```

More importantly, it also works in cases where the competing answer *doesn't*:

```
# need to be in a non-empty directory to demonstrate
$ touch a.txt b.txt c.txt

# put literal asterisks as separate words in our string
$ string='list * contains * asterisks'

# reading those using read -a works fine
$ IFS=' ' read -r -a list <<<"$string"

# whereas the array=( $string ) is NOT fine
$ IFS=' '; buggyList=( $string )

# print both arrays' contents
$ declare -p list buggyList
declare -a list=([0]="list" [1]="*" [2]="contains" [3]="*" [4]="asterisks")
declare -a buggyList=([0]="list" [1]="a.txt" [2]="b.txt" [3]="c.txt" [4]="contains" [5]="a.txt" [6]="b.txt" [7]="c.txt" [8]="asterisks")
```

As you can see, the `list=( $string )` answer gets filenames injected into its contents, but the `read -a` list contains *exactly* the word-split contents of your original string.